# Passing variables between action methods and show on view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a controller like below

```
           [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult Index(string number)
            {
             ....
                ServiceReference1.WebsiteInterfaceSoapClient APITest = new ServiceReference1.WebsiteInterfaceSoapClient();
                List<ServiceReference1.Student> ListStudents = APITest .CheckIDStudent("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", number).ToList();
             ....

              }
```

and I have a method like this

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ValidateS(StudentsDetails userDetails, string marksPoint)
    { 
            ....
    }
```

How can I pass all the data on `ListStudents` like `(ListStudents[0].ID, ListStudents[0].Name ...)` into `ValidateS` method and show them on `View`?

Comment: To clarify, you wanted to submit `List<ServiceReference1.Student> ListStudents` to `ValidateS()`? What is the model in your view anyway?

Comment: From ```Index```  the variable ```ListStudents``` store in session or tempData and change ```ValidateS``` action to ```HttpGet``` and you can read if you redirecting on something else. Or another way is after Post on Index get data from this Index action and again Post in another Action which is ValidateS but you have to change Form Action or use can use ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do the redirect function for `[HttpPost]` action. So you have to change your `ValidateS` action method to `[HttpGet]`. and use `TempData` feature.

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Index(string number)
{
    ServiceReference1.WebsiteInterfaceSoapClient APITest = new ServiceReference1.WebsiteInterfaceSoapClient();
    List<ServiceReference1.Student> ListStudents = APITest .CheckIDStudent("xxxxxxxxxxxxx", number).ToList();
    TempData["studentList"] = ListStudents;
}

[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> ValidateS(StudentsDetails userDetails, string marksPoint)
{ 
    List<ServiceReference1.Student> studentList = TempData["studentList"] as List<ServiceReference1.Student>;
}
```